# Codeigniter 4, load views from ajax are duplicated

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a problem, i have make a application with latest version of codeigniter 4.x.with full ajax system (0 reload page).

I explain :

1.My system, if the user clicks on the .className div it loads the page requested by ajax or simple load.

```
$(".devmode").on("click", function(){
    Clear();
    $("#page_details").load("dev", function() {
        window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", base_url+"dev");    
        console.log('✅ Page Loaded https://local.cms/public/dev');
    });
});
```

The page loads correctly with its content and the url is changed, so far so good.

So,
If the user loads the page directly through the url : https://local.cms/public/dev

The page is broken (no layout view), and if I include the layout in this page, then the layout will be duplicated when the above div is clicked.

I can't find a solution.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```
<?php
function is_ajax()
{
    return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest';
}
?>

<?php if(!is_ajax()): ?>
    <?= $this->extend('layouts/main-nomidle'); ?>
    <?= $this->section('content'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```